# Matplotlib savefig does not save axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, savefig

I'm trying to save a figure that works fine in IPython inline but does not save the figure to disk with the axes and titles included.

I am using TKAgg backend by default in matplotlibrc.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here? I have clearly set the xlabel and the tick marks work correctly in IPython inline plot.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt  
x = [1,2,3,3]
y = map(lambda(x): x * 2, x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_title("bleh")
ax.set_xlabel("xlabel")
ax.plot(x, y, 'r--')
fig.savefig("fig.png")
```

[image: Savefig image without axes labels]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same problem using Jupyter notebook and the command: %matplotlib notebook. The figure showed correctly in the notebook but didn't print axis and titles when saved with fig.savefig(). I changed %matplotlib notebook to %matplotlib inline and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 27):

Defining `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))` at the beginning, saving the file as `.jpg`, and setting `bbox_inches='tight'` solved the issue for me.

```py
plt.savefig('filename.jpg',bbox_inches='tight', dpi=150)
```

`bbox_inches='tight'` seems to fix cropping issues but it didn't work for `.png`.

Comment: In a practical sense this answer was best. I changed *only* from png to jpg, and the resulting image included the axes that I expected. Good enough for today. But it remains frustrating to me to not understand **why** these are different and to not understand how to output a .png as intended.

Comment: Molly's answer below explains why ;)

Comment: works with .tiff but adding bbox_inches arg

Answer (score 13):

Could be facecolor. I work in jupyter lab, and the facecolor default is set to black, so you don't see the axes, even though they are being drawn.

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor=(1, 1, 1))
```

sets the background color to white.

Comment: this is the correct solution for those having issues in jupyter notebooks. thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

You are setting the axis to start at the very bottom left of the figure and to fill up the entire thing. There's no room for the axis labels or the title.  Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt  
x = [1,2,3,3]
y = map(lambda(x): x * 2, x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.75,0.75]) # axis starts at 0.1, 0.1
ax.set_title("bleh")
ax.set_xlabel("xlabel")
ax.plot(x, y, 'r--')
fig.savefig("fig.png")
```

[image: plot with axis showing]

Comment: +1 Alternately just use `ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)`, or better yet, just `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`.

Comment: or `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, tight_layout=True)` (assuming your version of mpl is new enough)

Comment: or `plt.figure(tight_layout=True)`

Comment: Didn't work for me trying to create `png` file, switching to `jpg` fixed it

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the issue (in visual studio code jupyter extension) by changing the format from 'png' to 'jpg', along with the parameter 'plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)'.

Answer (score 3):

I was using Jupyter Notebook and Just change .png to .jpg and my problem is solved now Here is my code:

```
# changing the size of figure to 2X2
plt.figure(dpi=100, figsize=(15, 10))
plt.grid()
#display(plt.plot(year1, ratio1))
x = np.arange(1900, 2020, 5)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.title(ttile)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Ratio')
plt.plot(year,ratio)
plt.savefig('books_read.jpg', dpi = 300)
```

[Saved Image from the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvak5.jpg)

Comment: Helpful! Changing .png to .jpg worked outside Jupyter as well!

Answer (score 0):

Comment out `plt.show()` and instead call `plt.savefig('abc.png')`.