# How can I save a Matplotlib figure after changing the background color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, savefig

Using the Spyder IDE, I have created a matplotlib plot and changed the face (background) color of both the figure object and the axes object to black. When I try to save the figure using `plt.savefig(...)` the axes, title, and axes label are not included.

I have tried implementing the [standard advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib) of adding `bbox_inches='tight'` to the `plt.savefig()` function for when the axes are cut off:

```
plt.savefig("my_fig_name.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

To no avail. [Others suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576317/matplotlib-savefig-does-not-save-axes?noredirect=1&lq=1) that I change the plotting method to "inline" from "automatic" within either Jupyter Notebook or Spyder. This had no effect. I also tried to make sure there was enough room in the figure for my axes using:

```
fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.75,0.75])
```

This does not work either. Below is enough to reproduce my experience.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs, ys = [0,1], [0,1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6)) # Adding tight_layout=True has no effect
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# When the following block is commented out, the color of the 
# plot is unchanged and the plt.savefig function works perfectly

fig.patch.set_facecolor("#121111")
ax.set_facecolor("#121111")
ax.spines['top'].set_color("#121111")
ax.spines['right'].set_color("#121111")
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('white')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('white')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('white')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('white')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')

ax.set_title("My Graph's Title", color="white")

plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.xlabel("x-label")
plt.ylabel("y-label")

plt.savefig("my_fig_name.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

I am expecting to get an image like this:

[What I Expect to Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wwXa.png)

However, `plt.savefig(...)` gives me the following result:

[What I Actually Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01iR9.png)

Curiously, there seems to be white space around the plot which does not disappear even when I add the `tight_layout=True` parameter to the matplotlib figure constructor.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), tight_layout=True)
```

And, when I comment out the code which changes the face color of the plot, the figure is saved correctly with all the axes and labels displayed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to solve your problem, you just have to specify the `facecolor` keyword argument to your `plt.savefig` call, in this case :

```
plt.savefig("my_fig_name.png", bbox_inches="tight", facecolor="#121111")
```

which gives the intended `.png` output :

[image: correct_output]

For more information, see [plt.savefig documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).